# How to move pictures to different pages in word with a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to print postage labels as part of my online business. I have a macro to position the labels within a page but I would like a way to move the images to another page.

How could I move the 20 images that i have onto 5 separate pages with 4 images on each one using VBA macros? This is in mac by the way. Thanks.

```
Sub ImageResize()
'
' ImageResize Macro
' Resizes all images to a height of approx 99px
'
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            With .Shapes(i)
                .Height = 300
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
Sub ImagePos()
    '
    ' ImagePos Macro
    ' Positions 4 images per page.
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            With .Shapes(i)
                .Top = (i Mod 2) * 400
                If i Mod 4 = 3 Or i Mod 4 = 0 Then
                    .Left = 250
                End If
              Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
              End With

        Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: VB,NET is to vba as *car*  is to *carpet*.  Please fix your tags and read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Create one more `Sub` that will call your `ImageResize` and `ImagePos`subs for each of your pages.

```
Sub PicOnPages()

Dim p As Page

For Each p In ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages
    ImageResize
    ImagePos
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How could I move the 20 images that i have onto 5 separate pages with 4 images on each one using VBA macros? This is in mac by the way. Thanks.

Comment: you should have mentioned this in your question, instead of the irrelevant information about labels.